# CSS class selector is applying to a div with no class specified?

Tags: html, css, django, css-selectors

I am a bit new to CSS and have been struggling with why a selector has been applying to a classless div.
Here is my css code:

```
.page-header p, form{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    float: right;
    margin: 5px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

And here is my HTML code:

```
    <div class="page-header">

        {% if user.is_authenticated %} 

        <form action = "{% url 'logout' %}">
          <button type="submit">Logout</button>
        </form>
        <form action = "{% url 'errandlist' %}">
          <button type="submit">View my errands</button>
        </form>
        <p>Welcome {{ user.get_username }}.</p>

        {% else %}

        <form action = "{% url 'login' %}">
          <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
        <form action = "{% url 'signup' %}">
          <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
        </form>
        <p>You are not logged in.</p>

        {% endif %}

        <h1><a href="/">bingoHelper</a></h1>
    </div>

    <div>
    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
    </div>
```

The first div is properly applying the page-header class. The problem is, the bottom div is somehow using the page-header class even though there is no class specified.
For example, in the following HTML file that shows the block content, the form is floating right and has the Raleway font:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Sign up</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
  </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: It looks like it's applying it to the form, not the div.

Comment: It should be working just fine. Try adding class on the classless div.

Comment: @cmac Yes you're right, its applying it to the form within the second div, even though the second div is classless.

Comment: @Rigel1121 tried adding a class to the classless one, and even specified the values as !important, but it didn't help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take effect your css to `page-header` div, Specify the class in the `<form>` tags. See below css code:

```
.page-header p, .page-header form{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    float: right;
    margin: 5px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You css code:

```
.page-header p, form{
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  float: right;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

is applying the css to the p element inside your div with class .page-header **AND** form elements.

Remove the **, form** from your css, so it only applies to div elements with class .page-header

**UPDATE**

To have it apply to only form inside of div with class .page-header:

```
.page-header p, .page-header > form {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  float: right;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I want it to apply to the form elements within the first div, just not the form elements in the second div that doesn't specify the page-header class.